# Cambar el color del ratón para que tenga el mismo color de background segun el cursor se va posicionando

Tags: css, select, color, background

Tengo una select el cual cada option tiene un color diferente en su background.
Me gustaría cambiar el color del cursor al colocarse sobre un option al color que tiene ese option cuando el cursor no se ha posicionado sobre el. Esto es debido a que cuando el cursor se pone sobre el option se cambia el color del background así sería un modo de saber sobre que color estoy seleccionado.
Y de paso es la forma de obtener el valor de una propiedad de un objeto solo con CSS.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado? Cual es el codigo que actualmente tienes? Estos datos son cruciales para saber que estás haciendo y como lo estás haciendo.

Comment: Pon el codigo que has hecho hasta ahora

Comment: No creo que tal cosa sea posible, segun la respuesta de abajo puedes cambiar la imagen del icono al momento del hover, sin embargo no funciona en un select, javascript seria su solucion, pero no se que tan posible sea hacer lo que desea, ahora bien, existe una forma parecida, solo que en vez de usar un select puede usar una lista y con css darle estilos para emular un select, de esa forma podra usar el :hover para pasarle al cursor una imagen estatica, esto lo puede hacer por clase, es lo unico que se me ocurre que podria funcionar

Answer (score 0):

No es posible cambiar el color del cursos solo con `CSS` la única opción que tienes es cambiar la imagen del cursor. Utilizando `JavaScript` te resultaría mucho más fácil.

La única solución es esta.

```
.red-background:hover {
  cursor: url('path-to-image-cursor-red.png'), auto;    
}
```

Comment: El tiene un select con varios options, cada uno tiene un color asi que quiere que cuando pase por cada option el cursor se vuelva de ese color. No un color estandar como una imagen